# Java - Pass static method data to method Dynamically

Tags: java, android, static-methods

So Im trying to update a Box's position constantly, in my application but the way I retrieve the data is from a static method.
I've tried to do the following but with no luck..
Hope someone can navigate me of how to do this correctly.

```
Public class Foo extends service{
private ImageView box;
    static int dataX;
    static int dataY;

public void onCreate() {

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    box = new ImageView(this);
    box.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageX);


final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

                params.x = 0
                params.y = 0
        windowManager.addView(box, params);

           // The Box position should be changing constantly from the data I retrieve 

               box.setX(dataX);
               box..setY(dataY);
            windowManager.updateViewLayout(box, params);



..
..

// and the code above is not working, since im not passing the data correctly


}

public static void Data(int x, int y) {
// the data is being passed to this method
// x and y contains dynamic data which changes constantly
 dataX = x;
 dataY = y;

}

}
```

Comment: why you use a static method? is it a must ?

Comment: Yes in this case its a must for me :-)

Comment: ok, i think you shouldn't change the position in onCreate() method because it called only once try to find a method will call frequently or try to delete and re-draw it again to force onCreate() to work

Comment: @Sundar says: "It should work. As your code is fine, could you please show the code which you are trying to set as Box. Since it is a static variation, it holds the data what we set in Data method" and I agree: if Box  is anything like Point then I can't see any problem with the code you posted

Comment: But it dosen't :-). I've provided some more code

Comment: OK, that's better - does your class `Foo` extend from some custom class `service` or does it subclass `Service` like **the** `Service` in android?

Comment: It just extends the Android Service class

Comment: I guessed so. Then you can't simply go and call onCreate() again. Maybe you could use something which takes a look at the current values of dataX and dataY, compares them to the last known values and if there is a change then set a new position for the ImageView and have the WindowManager show the new position. The 'something'  could either be some worker thread or preferably a combo of ValueAnimator + ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener like [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#view-prop-animator)

Comment: Makes sense... >.<
Thought there was a way of doing to more easily...

Answer (score 0):

```
Public class Foo extends service{
private ImageView box;
    static int dataX;
    static int dataY;

public void onCreate() {

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    box = new ImageView(this);
    box.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageX);


    //Did you call the method like this?
      Data(dataX, dataY);
    //

final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

                params.x = 0
                params.y = 0
        windowManager.addView(box, params);

           // The Box position should be changing constantly from the data I retrieve 

               box.setX(dataX);
               box..setY(dataY);
            windowManager.updateViewLayout(box, params);



..
..

// and the code above is not working, since im not passing the data correctly


}

public static void Data(int x, int y) {
// the data is being passed to this method
// x and y contains dynamic data which changes constantly
 dataX = x;
 dataY = y;

}

}
```

Comment: Im not able to make it non-static in this case. Why can't I just save the value?? I did add some more code to the question please take a look

Comment: See my updated answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Remove the `static` word and where are you getting the data from?

Comment: Its complicated.. But from a JNI function

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite:

If this is for rmi, break the rmi interface out into it's own class with static methods.  It should be very simple.

All the work can be done in another non-static (normal) class and your static rmi class can retain a reference to that instance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? where should I call the onCreate method ? I can't call it inside a static method.

Comment: If I put all the logic inside of the Data() Method.. then it will never be created? I have to add it in onCreate???

Comment: And windowManager is a service.. and you can't use service object in a static method either.

Comment: I fully understand why you say it should be set in Data() method.. But its just not possible? I can't seems to get it to work....